# How to take an entry input from tkinter to an python script?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.6

I started programming in Python a few weeks ago. I have made a python program wherefore I am now making a gui with tkinter. The user input in the gui will be processed by the python program I already wrote. But when I run my program and want to use the value from an entry field in the python program it doesn't print the input value of the entry. But is prints 0,0 instead.

I got the following codes:
I got a class where I make a frame for my gui with tkinter (GUI_Pump.py):

```
import GUI as Gui
from GUI import *
import pump as Pomp

class Pump1(tk.Frame):
    p1_pump_spd1 = 0
    d_p1_mtr_on = 0

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text='Test case')
        label.place(x=380, y=10)

        def validate(new_text):
            if not new_text:  # the field is being cleared
                self.entered_number = 0
                return True

            try:
                self.entered_number = int(new_text)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False

        def ok():
            global p1_pump_spd1
            p1_pump_spd1 = p1.get()
            try:
                p1_pump_spd1
            except ValueError:
                p1_pump_spd1 = 0
            print(Pomp.p1_pump_spd)

        vcmd = parent.register(validate)
        p1 = tk.Entry(self, width=10, validate='key', validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))
        btn_ok = tk.Button(self, text='ok', command=ok, width=2)
        p1.place(x=230, y=20)
        btn_ok.place(x=290, y=20)
```

And I got my python program where I want to process the input value (pump.py)

```
from GUI import *
import GUI_Pump as GuiP

D_MH_MTR_SP_HLIM = 1500.0
D_MH_MTR_SP_LLIM = 0.0 

def fc33_limit_real(MIN, IN, MAX):
    if IN <= MIN:
        OUT = MIN
    elif IN >= MAX:
        OUT = MAX
    else:
        OUT = IN
    return OUT

p1_spd = GuiP.Pump1.p1_pump_spd1
p1_pump_spd = fc33_limit_real(D_MH_MTR_SP_LLIM, p1_spd, D_MH_MTR_SP_HLIM)
```

But if I print p1_pump_p1_spd I get always 0,0, no matter what I fill in to the entry field. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are assigning the user's input to the global variable `p1_pump_spd1` within the `GUI_Pump` module, but are retrieving the value from the class attribute `p1_pump_spd1` within the `Pump1` class.  The two variables are utterly unrelated to each other.

Comment: @jasonharper how could I make these variables related to each other?

Comment: Have a look at [Understanding Class and Instance Variables in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3).

Comment: @figbeam Thank you for your advise. I have got it working now.